# How do you uniformly sample spans from a bounded line?

Tags: python, sampling, uniform-distribution

Suppose you have a bounded and continuous line. For example, the line could include all real numbers between 0 and 3. How do you sample spans from the line such that...

- Any point on the line has an equal chance of being included in the span.
- The distribution of span lengths is uniform.

---

My attempted solution:

```
import random

max_length = 15.0
bounds = (0.0, 3.0)

length = random.uniform(0, max_length)
start = random.uniform(bounds[0] - length, bounds[1])
end = min(start + length, bounds[1])
start = max(start, bounds[0])
```

This solution is able to fulfill the first criterion and not the second criterion.

**EDIT:** Following the lead of BruceET, I have plotted the distribution of span lengths:

```
import random
from matplotlib import pyplot
import seaborn

max_length = 6
bounds = (0, 3)
num_samples = 10**6

samples = []
for _ in range(num_samples):
    length = random.uniform(0, max_length)
    start = random.uniform(bounds[0] - length, bounds[1])
    end = min(start + length, bounds[1])
    start = max(start, bounds[0])
    samples.append(end - start)

seaborn.distplot(
    samples,
    hist=True,
    kde=True,
    bins=30,
    color='darkblue',
    hist_kws={'edgecolor': 'black'},
    kde_kws={'linewidth': 1})
pyplot.show()
```

[image: Distribution of span lengths]

Comment: There are exactly two ways of doing this: (1) make the "spans" all have zero length (and distribute their endpoints uniformly); (2) make them all have length 3.  If by "uniform" you allow *discrete* uniform distributions, there are other solutions.  For instance, draw the intervals $[0,3/2)$ and $[3/2, 3)$ with equal probabilities of $1/4$ and draw the intervals $[0,3/4),$ $[3/4,3/2),$ $[3/2,9/4),$ and $[9/4,3)$ with equal probabilities of $1/8.$ The distribution of span lengths is uniform on the set $\{3/4,3/2\}.$ Is this the sort of thing you are looking for?

Comment: Thank you for your creative approach! You are right and that would work. It wouldn't be ideal for me. I should clarify that I'd also like to maximize the variety. For context, this solution will be used to train a machine learning model and diversity is important.

Comment: Generalize, then. For instance, let $n\ge 2$ be a positive integer.  Consider the sequence $$(a) = (a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)=\frac{1}{n!},\frac{2}{n!},\ldots,\frac{n}{n!}.$$ Each of the $a_i$ is the reciprocal of the *integer* $n!/i.$ Thus, you may sample $i$ *uniformly* from the set $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ and then, conditional on $i,$ sample a span $[(k-1)a_i, ka_i)$ *uniformly* from $k\in\{1,2,\ldots, n!/n\}.$

Answer (score 3):

Comment: You're having trouble with your second simulation because the 'span' of several uniform random variables is is *not* uniform.

In R, the function `range` gives the endpoints, taking the difference gives
what you call the 'span'.

Here is a simulation in R of the span lengths from 100,000 samples of size $n=5$ from $\mathsf{Unif}(0, 3).$

```
set.seed(2020)
span.5 = replicate(10^6, diff(range(runif(5,0,3))))
summary(span.5)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
0.07294 1.63716 2.05782 1.99968 2.41826 2.99932 
hist(span.5, prob=T, col="skyblue2")
curve((1/3)*dbeta(x/3, 4, 2), add=T, col="red", lwd=2)
```

[image]

Comment: Yes. Your right. Since the above problem allows me to choose the `length`, I have been thinking about picking a `length` to correct for that.

Comment: In case it helps, I just now included the density function of the theoretical 4-parameter beta distribution.

Comment: Thanks for your comment and that's helpful. I updated the question with the current distribution that I am seeing.

Comment: Do you know the name of the distribution that I posted above? I think if I can find the inverse of that distribution then I can correct for it.

Comment: Not sure what correction you have in mind. But name of dist'n hinted in the R code that draws the red density line. It is a 4-parameter beta distribution with support $(0, 3)$ and shape parameters 4 and 2. Maybe see Wikipedia on 'beta distribution'.

Comment: @MichaelPetrochuk if you enforce the lengths to be uniform by IRT or such, the sampling probability along the line will no longer be uniform. Your criteria are more fundamentally incompatible: any points near the center of the line are "easier" to sample because of overlaps (e.g. think of all possible placements for segments of length $2$), so unless you prevent overlaps or enforce some kind of correlation between segment position and length, which you probably don't want, I don't see how this is possible. Sampling along a circle, on the other hand, would be easy, if that helps...